# Embedding image slider into UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, slider

I would like to add a photo slider into a UITableViewCell, as in the appstore app description.
There is a slider with the app screen shots.

I tried adding a EGOPhotoViewController, but I'm pretty stuck.

Any idea on what is the best solution to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UIScrollView`, several `UIImageView` in it and and `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`.